# What does this select statement do? How the filter expression is considered

Tags: c#

```
if (dtMonitorOnly.Select("MONITOR_TRANSIT_NUMBER ='" + transit + "' and MONITOR_GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '" + dr["Account #"].ToString() + "'").Length == 1)
    obj.XFLAG2 = dtMonitorOnly.Select("MONITOR_TRANSIT_NUMBER ='" + transit + "' and MONITOR_GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '" + dr["Account #"].ToString() + "'")[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
else
    obj.XFLAG2 = "";
```

Comment: Can you read this code yourself?

Comment: reply soon!! we gottu realiee know abt this code

Answer (score 3):

It's a very inefficient way of writing a `SingleOrDefault()` implementation. Only difference is (if that is possible with the not disclosed other code) that if there are more than one result sets, it would behave the same if as there where none.

Comment: Can u pls tell d implementation of select

Comment: How would I tell you the implementation of `Select`? It's your code, you didn't include it - how would I know?